# SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean Having clause

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am trying to process some data from a table using SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean. 
The only problem is that I need to use "Having" clause in order to retrieve only the needed info (there is a huge amount of data we don't need).
It seems that SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean knows about "Where" clause, but it doesn't implement nothing about "Having".

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing within Spring Batch that supports that natively unfortunately.  You will need to write your own implementation to do that or use the `JdbcCursorItemReader` instead of the paging one.